# How to create a character encoding from scratch

Tags: dictionary, fonts, character-encoding, binary, compression

What I want to know is if it is possible to create a character set like ASCII for example from scratch!

So, I have tried to do this but the only thing I found was software that allow me to change the existing characters for an existing character set, once again like ASCII..

What I really want to do is to determine which code (Binary / Octal / Decimal / Hexadecimal) corresponds to a particular character (that I will create by my own). My problem is that I don't want to have a limited dictionary size like the 128 characters of ASCII or any other existing character set. So, do you know of any way I can do this ? Any software ? The result I want to achieve is to have a normal ttf file (i.e. myfont.ttf), install it, and then use my new character set in software like notepad!

The dictionairy must be the size that I want, that is very important.. not more than I need..
of course i could change some characters of UTF-8 character set for example but then i would have characters that i don't need.. and as I want this to test a compression system then the size of the dictionary must be exact.

Example of want I need:

```
Binary code      Character      OCT      DEC      HEX
00000000         X              000      00       00
00000001         Y              001      01       01
00000010         A              002      02       02
```

... and then it continues until any limit.. it might be 150 characters, 500, 17!

I think this is pretty simple to understand.. do you know how can I do this ?

Comment: The question has some very basic concepts mixed, like “glyph” versus “characters”. (Character codes define codes for characters, not glyphs. Rendering systems may have their own codes for glyphs.) Referring to “255 characters of ASCII” also shows conceptual confusion. ASCII has exactly 128 code points. It is impossible to guess what you are really asking, even if we read your comment below (and a question should be written so that it is understandable as such, without peeking at answers, still less to comments on answers).

Comment: i just edited my question

Comment: OK I think I misunderstood you yesterday, but I think the issue is that if you create a new character set, it won't be supported by current text editors. (So I'm still not sure if I'm not maybe just understanding you wrong?...) You would need to patch the software (or at least some libraries) to support your encoding and you won't be able to open the files in any text editor without exclusive support for your encoding...

Answer (score 1):

The character set defines the mapping from glyphs to binary codes. As I understand you probably don't want to create a new character set (which is something I wouldn't recommend doing except for educational reasons anyway, as there are already countless charsets and associated issues around).
You probably want to take eg. the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) charset and replace some of the glyphs which you wouldn't use otherwise with your own ones. (I guess you have to lookup font designing softwares in the web.)
As with the limitation of the number of glyphs you have, it is actually pretty high for UTF-8 but there is one. You could take a similar approach as some dingbats fonts do and place glyphs for chars that are easy to type. Say a => a potato, b => ketchup, etc... Then in notepad (or another text processor of choice) one can switch to your font when they want to enter a special glyph, type eg. a, and go back to the main font to continue writing.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for your problem highly differs according to its actual context.
Lets see one context out of a million for example: If i were to create a video game using custom letters in its GUI, my approach to this would be to simply decide what character is what byte on paper, then interpreted each byte using bitmaps. By bitmaps i am refering to files on Windows with .BMP extension.

- How did i draw, or control bitmaps?
- Well i could use a programming language like c# and visual studio for example, to create the necessary BMP files, then loaded them in orderly to the games GUI picture by picture.

My research on this is that my approach would be narrow minded due to the way that the encoding matters, not the look of the characters, however i was able to do it in a given context.

If you would like to create letters vectorgrafically, meaning that you were possessing pre-fonts at the creation of your letters, look up this link about vectorgrafical fonts and Bezier quadratic curves:
https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM01/Chap1.html

TLDR.:
I do not actualy know where would you need custom letters, but keep in mind that you must make the main stream character users (like windows, linux, etc...) to somehow notify your efforts to create an arbitrary character set aswell, not just one character set, which one is different to the existing ASCII, or Unicode. It was rather hard to do since Unicode exists already. The real problem is that these character sets are static and not dynamic. It was pretty easy in a hardware point of view to create an arbitrary character set as large as ASCII, because typing is abstract in your machines point of view. There is one slight issue is that you would need a translator method that translates between your, and existing encoding maps. This was not an issue as long as you were not even interested in using existing features with your custom character set.

I am also looking for a way to do this for a different reason however. I would like to create a character mapping for my own language, or for an arbitrary language. For example in my language there are way less than 128 letters, but i still need to use the unicode encoding to get along with. I would like to create such an encoding map that understands my languages letters at as small resolution as ASCII does the english letters.
The reason why i do this is because there is a lot of compound letters due to latinic letters are too few to write with in my language. And i would like to be able to program a type of AI or system that can comprehend compound words, and agglutanations more easily. This is a problem because for example compound words might contain compound letters at their connecting ends, thus it is harder to search for typoes, and other grammatical errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).